# How to change the size of the system cursor in a macosx cocoa app programmatically using swift or objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, nscursor

I've tried to set it's global size using this code:

```
-(void)setOption {
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSDictionary *olddict = [defaults persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.universalaccess"];
   NSMutableDictionary *newdict = [olddict mutableCopy];
   [newdict setObject:@4.0 forKey:@"mouseDriverCursorSize"];
   [defaults setPersistentDomain:newdict forName:@"com.apple.universalaccess"];
   [defaults synchronize];
   NSLog(@"Cursor size set to %@", newdict);
}
```

And I can see in the NSLog that it changed it but I don't know how to restart/reset the system cursor in order for the cursor to change to the specified size.

Does anybody know a better way to change it's size programmatically or how to restart the system cursor after the defaults change?

**EDIT(about duplication):** My question is unique because I can't use applescript in resolving this like the answer provided in the other topic. Also the topic has been created in 2013, and seems outdated. Maybe things have changed a little since then. Also maybe Swift would be a viable solution for resolving this. Who knows? All these arguments make it clear that this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programatically change the cursor size on a Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510870/how-to-programatically-change-the-cursor-size-on-a-mac)

Comment: I've followed that topic but didn't met my requirements. That's why I asked a different question. Thanks for your interest, though!

Comment: any updates ? did you try my suggestion below ?

Comment: Commented under your response. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CGError state = CGSShowCursor(CGSDefaultConnection) ;
    if (state != kCGErrorSuccess) NSLOG(@"error : %d",state);
```

maybe try it with `CGSShowCursor(CGSMainConnectionID())`

This might also help : https://github.com/alexzielenski/Mousecape/blob/1d534b1e076b07a01b80364be23c88c8439028bc/Mousecape/mousecloak/NSCursor_Private.h

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. So basically now I'm searching for new solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Warning. This code is not based on what is saved in preferences so combine it:

```
  float cursorScale = 2;
  cursorScale = MAX(1, MIN(cursorScale,4));
  int connectionID = CGSMainConnectionID();
  CGSSetCursorScale(connectionID, cursorScale);
```

to get the size

```
  CGSGetCursorScale(connectionID, &cursorScale);
```

,

```
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSDictionary *olddict = [defaults persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.universalaccess"];
   NSMutableDictionary *newdict = [olddict mutableCopy];
   [newdict setObject:@4.0 forKey:@"mouseDriverCursorSize"];
   [defaults setPersistentDomain:newdict forName:@"com.apple.universalaccess"];
   [defaults synchronize];
   NSLog(@"Cursor size set to %@", newdict);
```

CREDITS: [Alex Zielenski](https://github.com/alexzielenski/Mousecape/blob/master/Mousecape/mousecloak/scale.m)